# Retrieve rows with null date values

Tags: mysql, null

I want to retrieve the names of all employees who were absent for a range of time.

I need a query which can return me employees with null attendance. The data structure is shown below:

```
date: 17-07-2012

empname | intime | outtime | teamtype 
abs     | NULL   | NULL    | PD
dfg     | NULL   | NULL    | PD

date: 18-07-2012

empname | intime | outtime | teamtype 
abs     | NULL   | NULL    | PD
ghf     | NULL   | NULL    | PD
dfg     | NULL   | NULL    | PD
```

Comment: Please provide more info such as table structure, sample data, query tried before. Thanks.

Comment: How does your data relate to the dates in your sample? Are you looking for all employees who were **not** present on the specified date?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the list of employees who were *not* present at a specified time. Note that I've guessed table names and columns since they're not included in your question:

```
select empName
from employees left outer join attendance
    on employees.id = attendance.employee_id and :DATE between intime and outtime
where
    attendance.employee_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select empName from tblName where intime is null
```

Comment: (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') is the range part u missed